# Python: Stop reading a package

Tags: python

I'd like to know how to stop reading a package.

For example,

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
FLAG= True if 'TEST' in os.environ else False
if not FLAG:  return

def test():
  print 'test is defined'
```

but actually 'return' fails:

```
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function
```

The purpose is to check some system dependencies, and if they are not satisfied, stop reading the package.

sys.exit(0) does not work since it stops the entire program.

An alternative solution may be deciding to import or not to import OUTSIDE the package, like:

```
FLAG= True if 'TEST' in os.environ else False
if FLAG:  import THE_PACKAGE
```

but I think this decision making is better to be done INSIDE the package, since it is the common process.

Is there any good way, like 'return' from a package?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short -- you can't.  There are a few (hacky) workarounds.  e.g. you could `raise ImportError` and rely on the user catching it, or you could define everything in the body of a function that only gets executed if conditions are met:

```
def _main():
    class Foo(object):
        pass
    global Foo

    ...

if condition:
    _main()
```

This wouldn't be my recommendation (it'd get pretty cumbersome pretty quickly).

The "best" example I can think of is python's [`os`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/os.py) package -- I'd recommend you study the methods presented there.  Basically, they detect the system and then import functions satisfying the appropriate interface into the `os` namespace using `from XYZ import *`.  This is a solution that you (more or less) already described in your question and is the way that I would definitely recommend doing it.